# How to asynchronously submit POST request using React/Node.js/Express framework?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, asynchronous, fetch

I am attempting to set up an asynchronous POST request using `fetch` with React and the Express framework with Node.js.

When the form is submitted, I can see on the server side that the data is being received by node.js.

My difficulty is that after the form is submitted on the client side, the web page acts like it is rendering for a very long time, and the browser says `Waiting for localhost...` while it is loading.

If I add `res.send('received POST data')` on the server side, I am redirected to `localhost:9000/jobSearch` which displays 'received POST data'.

I would like to retrieve data from `localhost:9000/jobSearch` and display it on the client side at `localhost:3000` without reloading the page. I have read that this might be easier using axios or jQuery, however I would like to do this using only React and Express with Node.js. I have copied several examples, but I cannot get my implementation to work. Am I missing something?

**React:**

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FormControl, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'


class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            jobSearch: {
                jobTitle: '',
                location: ''
            }
        }
    }


    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { jobTitle, location } = this.state;

        fetch('http://localhost:9000/jobSearch',{
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state.jobSearch)
        }).then(res => res.json())
          .then((result) => {
              console.log('callback for the response')
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:9000/jobSearch">
                <FormControl name="jobTitle"/>
                <FormControl name="location"/>
                <Button type="submit">Find Jobs</Button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

**Node.js:**

jobSearch.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('req.body here -> ', req.body)
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Remove the method and action and put onSubmit on the form or button components

Answer (score 0):

Default HTML form behavior is to redirect to new page when the form is submitted. this is not expected behavior in most scenarios from a web application. its recommended to use `controlled component` to achieve this behavior. more info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

basic idea behind this is to use a form submit handle function. this function will be called with a [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html). the default html form behavior is prevented by calling `preventDefault` on the `SyntheticEvent`. implementation looks something like this:

```
class Form extends React.Component {

  handleSubmit = (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // on submit logic
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        // form fields
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```